# Yii 1.0: How to know whether the renderPartial is success of fail

Tags: php, yii

In Yii 1.0 framework, how to know whether the renderPartial is success of fail?
Assume that $information holds an associative array which only running the content in 'detail/submitForm'. See sample below:

```
$this->renderPartial('detail/submitForm', array('information' => $information));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii 1.0: how to know whether the renderPartial is success of fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962216/yii-1-0-how-to-know-whether-the-renderpartial-is-success-of-fail)

Answer (score 0):

If something goes wrong rendering the view, you will get the PHP error/warning/notice. 
In case the rendering is successful, then you will get a string containing the rendered view (which will be sent back to the browser by the controller, and the browser will process and display it).