# Yii 1.0: how to know whether the renderPartial is success of fail?

Tags: php, yii

In Yii 1.0 framework, how to know whether the renderPartial is success of fail? Assume that $information holds an associative array which only running the content in 'detail/submitForm'. See sample below:

```
$this->renderPartial('detail/submitForm', array('information' => $information));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you could wrap it in try/catch block and use a flag variable, like so:

```
// flag variable to hold renderPartial's status, set to true initially
$renderSuccess = true;
try {
    $this->renderPartial('detail/submitForm', array('information' => $information));
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    $renderSuccess = false;
}
```